# Count how many times an event occurred or a metric was reported using PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

I use Victoria Metrics to track IOT Devices. Whenever device connects/disconnects i insert a metric into Victoria Metrics. My metric name is devcon_s.
i can query data using this -
devcon_s{device_id="something"}

But I want to know how frequent device disconnect in a day. I trie queries like this -
`sum_over_time(count_values without(kd_id) ("value", devcon_s{kd_id="something"} == 0)[1d:])`
or

`count_over_time((devcon_s{kd_id="something"} == 0)[1d:])`

With step equal to 1d or 1h. But it doesnt give me actual number of count the event was reported but something else which doesnt make sense to me.
Am i doing something wrong ? Or is it not possible to count actual number of values in promQL

Answer (score 1):

[MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) provides `count_le_over_time(m[d], le)` function, which returns the number of raw data points that have values smaller or equal to `le` on the time range `[d]` for each time series matching `m`.

The following query should return the number of raw data points with value<=0 for the last day:

```
count_le_over_time(devcon_s{k_id="something"}[1d])
```